# maven pom to call other poms in sub directories

Tags: java, linux, bash, maven

Have a project where we have 8 Projects in Eclipse, each with its own pom.xml

Right now call them via an sh file (series of cd, mvns, sleep for 3 seconds so we can see if error and ctrl-c)

Is there a way to call the various poms from within another master pom and only continue if current project mvn ran successfully?

If not via maven then via ant or other plug in / linux script edits? Example please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is using a multi-module Maven project as described on this page: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

A code example can be found in section 6.2 (http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you - had to put this pom.xml in my workspace folder ... and it worked great :-)